# detect event from $("input").val() and then run function js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to recognize a function event with "on" and then run console.log but input, keyup, keydown or change doesnt call this change.

I have the write function.

```
function write(){
  $("input").val("1");
}
```

And then this query for checking the event:

```
$("input").on("change",function(){
  console.log('input changed!');
});

write();//it doesnt get the change function
```

Custom HTML:

```
<input type="text">
```

The reason of this is that i want to enter values with a custom js keyboard (that's why i cant use keyup or keydown) but i cant get the event of .val() from jquery.

Comment: IIRC, the "change" event won't fire until the input loses focus. Perhaps your "custom js keyboard" should emit events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to trigger the event after you set `.val` - jQuery doesn't trigger events automatically when you change it in code.

```js
function write(){
  $("input").val("1").trigger("change");
}

$("input").on("change",function(){
  console.log('input changed!');
});

write();//it doesnt get the change function
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">
```

Comment: This was the answer i was looking for, i didnt know it was a duplicate because i didnt know how exactly make the question but thanks!